# asp.net page is loading very slow

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, sharepoint

Well i'm working an application which use a connection with SharePoint to load the list items.

I'm also using a dynamic table so new rows can be added by the user.

It takes more than 7 seconds before my page is asp.net page. I checked this with firebug.

Below is the code of my page:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

namespace AdminCareWeb
{
public partial class DocumentToevoegen : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    #region globalevars
    SharePointContextToken contextToken;
    string accessToken;
    Uri sharepointUrl;
    string contextTokenString;
    string logoHoofding;
    int initNumRows = 15;
    public string jsSharePointURL;

    //Instanties aanmaken van de klasses
    static List<TableRow> TableRows = new List<TableRow>();
    static Dictionary<int, Artikels> dicArtikels = new Dictionary<int, Artikels>();

    Document huidigDocument = new Document();
    Klanten huidigeKlant = new Klanten();
    #endregion


    #region properties
    private int numOfRows
    {
        get
        {
            if (ViewState["RowsCount"] == null)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                return (int)ViewState["RowsCount"];
            }
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["RowsCount"] = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string vorigePagina = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();

            //Controleer of de pagina gerefreshd werd of voor het eerst geladen wordt.
            if (!vorigePagina.Contains("DocumentToevoegen.aspx"))
            {
                TableRows.Clear();
                //Als de pagina voor de eerste keer geladen wordt moet de tabel leeggemaakt worden.
                dicArtikels.Clear();
            }

            //Generate the Rows on Initial Load
            if (!Page.IsPostBack && dicArtikels.Count == 0)
            {
                numOfRows = initNumRows;
                Artikels artikel = new Artikels();

                for (int i = 0; i < numOfRows; i++)
                {
                    dicArtikels.Add(i, artikel);

                }
            }

            GenerateTable(0, numOfRows);

            //Controleer of security tokens al aanwezig zijn. Indien deze niet aanwezig zijn maak ze globaal aan.
            if (PassThrough.contextTokenString != null)
            {
                ClientContext clientContext = ContextTokensOphalen();
                jsSharePointURL = PassThrough.sharepointUrl.ToString();



            }
            else if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                Response.Write("Could not find a context token.");
                return;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            huidigDocument.log("DocumentToevoegen.aspx", "Page_Load", ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    }

    protected void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClientContext clientContext = ContextTokensOphalen();

        try
        {
            bool foutief = false; ;
            string adresgegevens = "";

            #region parameters ophalen
            Parameters ledig = new Parameters();
            ledig.ledigParameters();
            huidigDocument.ParametersLookup(clientContext);
            huidigDocument.Parameters1Tekstregel(clientContext);
            huidigDocument.ParametersMeerdereTekstregels(clientContext);
            huidigDocument.ParametersJaNeen(clientContext);

            //Controleer of de bankgegevens ingevuld werden.

            if (Parameters.Bankgegevens != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Parameters.Bankgegevens))
            {
                foutief = false;
                lblBankgegevens.Text = Parameters.Bankgegevens.Replace("\r\n", "<br />");
            }

            if (Parameters.Naam != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Parameters.Naam))
            {
                foutief = false;
                adresgegevens += Parameters.Naam + "<br>";
            }

            if (Parameters.Adres != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Parameters.Adres))
            {
                foutief = false;
                adresgegevens += Parameters.Adres + "<br>";
            }

            if (Parameters.Adres2 != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Parameters.Adres2))
            {
                foutief = false;
                adresgegevens += Parameters.Adres2 + "<br>";
            }

            if (Parameters.Postcode != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Parameters.Postcode))
            {
                foutief = false;
                adresgegevens += Parameters.Postcode;
            }

            if (Parameters.Plaats != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Parameters.Plaats))
            {
                foutief = false;
                adresgegevens += " " + Parameters.Plaats + "<br>";
            }

            if (Parameters.Telefoon != null && Parameters.Telefoon.Length > 3)
            {
                foutief = false;
                adresgegevens += "Tel: " + Parameters.Telefoon + "<br>";
            }

            if (Parameters.GSM != null && Parameters.GSM.Length > 3)
            {
                foutief = false;
                adresgegevens += "GSM: " + Parameters.GSM + "<br>";
            }

            if (Parameters.Fax != null && Parameters.Fax.Length > 3)
            {
                foutief = false;
                adresgegevens += "Fax: " + Parameters.Fax + "<br>";
            }

            if (Parameters.Ondernemingsnummer != null && Parameters.Ondernemingsnummer.Length > 3)
            {
                foutief = false;
                adresgegevens += "BTW " + Parameters.Ondernemingsnummer + "<br>";
            }

            if (Parameters.RPR != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Parameters.RPR))
            {
                foutief = false;
                adresgegevens += "RPR " + Parameters.RPR + "<br>";
            }

            if (Parameters.Website != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Parameters.Website))
            {
                foutief = false;
                adresgegevens += Parameters.Website + "<br>";
            }

            if (Parameters.Email != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Parameters.Email))
            {
                foutief = false;
                adresgegevens += Parameters.Email + "<br>";
            }


            if (Parameters.Logo != null && Parameters.LogoHoofding.ToString() == "")
            {
                foutief = false;
                imgLogo.ImageUrl = Parameters.Logo;
                imgLogo.Visible = true;

            }

            if (Parameters.LogoHoofding.ToString() != "")
            {
                logoHoofd.Style.Add("BACKGROUND-IMAGE", "url(" + Parameters.LogoHoofding + ");width:794px;");
                foutief = false;
                logoHoofding = Parameters.LogoHoofding;
                imgLogo.Visible = false;
            }

            if (Parameters.Logovoet != null)
            {
                foutief = false;
                imgVoet.ImageUrl = Parameters.Logovoet;
                imgVoet.Visible = true;
                imgVoet.Height = 140;
                imgVoet.Width = 794;
            }

            if (!foutief) { lblAdresgegevens.Text = adresgegevens; }

            #endregion
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            huidigDocument.log("DocumentToevoegen.aspx", "Page_Load", ex.Message.ToString());
        }


        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            //Huidige datum ophalen volgens het Belgisch formaat.
            //Datum wordt gebruikt om de Documentdatum in te stellen en de vervaldatum.
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
            txtDocumentDatum.Text = dt.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
            dt = dt.AddDays(30);
            txtVervaldatum.Text = Parameters.Vervaldatum;

            ddlLand.SelectedValue = "20";
            lblIntraCom.Text = "";


            try
            {
                #region klanten ophalen

                //Klanten invullen met de opgehaalde waardes uit een Dictionary
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> klant in huidigeKlant.KlantenOphalen())
                {
                    string naam = klant.Value;
                    ddlKlant.Items.Add(new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem(naam, naam));
                }

                #endregion

                #region dagboeken ophalen

                //Dagboeken invullen met de opgehaalde waardes uit een Dictionary
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> dagboeken in huidigDocument.Dagboeken())
                {
                    //ddlDagboek.Items.Clear();
                    string ID = dagboeken.Key;
                    string omschrijving = dagboeken.Value;
                    ddlDagboek.Items.Add(new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem(omschrijving, ID));
                }

                #endregion

                #region postcodes ophalen

                //Postcodes invullen met de opgehaalde waardes uit een Dictionary
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> postcode in huidigeKlant.Postcodes())
                {
                    string ID = postcode.Key;
                    string gemeente = postcode.Value;
                    ddlGemeente.Items.Add(new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem(gemeente, ID));
                }

                huidigDocument.DocumentNummerOpvragen(int.Parse(ddlDagboek.SelectedValue));
                txtDocNr.Text = huidigDocument.documentCode + " / " + huidigDocument.huidigDocumentNummer;

                #endregion

                #region landen ophalen

                //Landen invullen met de opgehaalde waardes uit een Dictionary
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> land2 in huidigeKlant.Landen())
                {
                    string ID = land2.Key;
                    string land = land2.Value;
                    ddlLand.Items.Add(new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem(land, ID));
                }

                huidigDocument.DocumentTitelOpvragen(int.Parse(ddlDagboek.SelectedValue));
                lblDocumentTitel.Text = huidigDocument.documentTitel;

                #endregion
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                huidigDocument.log("DocumentToevoegen.aspx", "Page_Load", ex.Message.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    private void GenerateTable(int existing, int rowsCount)
    {
        try
        {
            //Alle data halen uit de PassThrough class om opnieuw een connectie te maken met SharePoint
            ClientContext clientContext = ContextTokensOphalen();

            Table table = Page.Form.FindControl("tblArtikels") as Table;

            if (table == null)
            {
                table = new Table();
                table.ID = "tblArtikels";
                Page.Form.Controls.Add(table);
            }
            else
            {
                if (existing == 0)
                {
                    table.Controls.Clear();
                }
            }

            //The number of Columns to be generated
            const int colsCount = 6;//You can changed the value of 3 based on you requirements

            // Now iterate through the table and add your controls
            for (int i = existing; i < rowsCount; i++)
            {
                if (!dicArtikels.ContainsKey(i))
                {
                    Artikels artikel = new Artikels();
                    dicArtikels.Add(i, artikel);
                }

                TableRow row = new TableRow();
                for (int j = 0; j < colsCount; j++)
                {
                    TableCell cell = new TableCell();
                    //means the first column of the Table
                    if (j == 0)
                    {
                        cell.Width = 40;
                        //Create the CheckBox
                        CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
                        // Set a unique ID for each CheckBox
                        cb.ID = "CheckBoxRow_" + i + "Col_" + j;
                        // Add the control to the FIRST TableCell
                        cell.Controls.Add(cb);
                        // Add the TableCell to the TableRow
                        row.Cells.Add(cell);

                    }
                    //2de kolom
                    else if (j == 1)
                    {
                        cell.Width = 60;
                        //Create the TextBox
                        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
                        // Set a unique ID for each TextBox
                        tb.ID = "TextBoxRow_" + i + "Col_" + j;
                        tb.Width = 40;
                        tb.EnableViewState = true;
                        tb.EnableTheming = true;
                        // Add the control to the TableCell
                        cell.Controls.Add(tb);
                        // Add the TableCell to the TableRow
                        row.Cells.Add(cell);
                    }
                    //Kolom 3
                    else if (j == 2)
                    {
                        cell.Width = 310;
                        cell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
                        //Create the TextBox
                        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
                        // Set a unique ID for each TextBox
                        tb.ID = "TextBoxRow_" + i + "Col_" + j;
                        tb.Width = 290;
                        tb.EnableViewState = true;
                        tb.EnableTheming = true;
                        tb.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;
                        // Add the control to the TableCell
                        cell.Controls.Add(tb);
                        // Add the TableCell to the TableRow
                        row.Cells.Add(cell);

                    }
                    //Kolom 4
                    else if (j == 3)
                    {
                        cell.Width = 160;
                        cell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
                        //Create the TextBox
                        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
                        // Set a unique ID for each TextBox
                        tb.ID = "TextBoxRow_" + i + "Col_" + j;
                        //tb.TextChanged += new EventHandler(txtArtikelPrijs_TextChanged);
                        tb.Width = 140;
                        tb.EnableViewState = true;
                        tb.EnableTheming = true;
                        // Add the control to the TableCell
                        cell.Controls.Add(tb);
                        // Add the TableCell to the TableRow
                        row.Cells.Add(cell);
                    }
                    //Kolom 5
                    else if (j == 4)
                    {
                        cell.Width = 160;
                        cell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
                        //Create the TextBox
                        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
                        // Set a unique ID for each TextBox
                        tb.ID = "TextBoxRow_" + i + "Col_" + j;
                        //tb.TextChanged += new EventHandler(txtArtikelPrijs_TextChanged);
                        tb.Width = 140;
                        tb.Enabled = false;
                        tb.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#F2F2F2");
                        tb.TabIndex = -1;
                        tb.EnableViewState = true;
                        tb.EnableTheming = true;
                        // Add the control to the TableCell
                        cell.Controls.Add(tb);
                        // Add the TableCell to the TableRow
                        row.Cells.Add(cell);
                    }
                    //Kolom 6
                    else if (j == 5)
                    {
                        cell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
                        cell.Width = 64;
                        //Create the TextBox
                        DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
                        // Set a unique ID for each TextBox
                        ddl.ID = "DropDownRow_" + i + "Col_" + j;
                        ddl.Width = 50;
                        ddl.TabIndex = -1;
                        ddl.EnableViewState = true;
                        ddl.EnableTheming = true;
                        ddl.Items.Clear();
                        //Lijst met artikelen ophalen en dropdown opvullen
                        List oListBTW = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Lijst BTWcodes");

                        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();


                        CamlQuery cQBTW = new CamlQuery();
                        cQBTW.ViewXml = "<View>"
                        + "<Query>"
                        + "</Query>"
                        + "</View>";

                        Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection btwListItem = oListBTW.GetItems(cQBTW);
                        clientContext.Load(btwListItem);
                        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                        foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem btwItem in btwListItem)
                        {
                            string btwcode = btwItem["bcCode"].ToString();
                            string btwpercentage = btwItem["bcBTW"].ToString();
                            ddl.Items.Add(new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem(btwpercentage, btwcode));
                        }

                        if (i >= initNumRows && ddlBTWregime.Items.Count > 0)
                        {
                            if (ddlBTWregime.SelectedItem.Value == "Medecontractant" || ddlBTWregime.SelectedItem.Value == "intracom goederen" || ddlBTWregime.SelectedItem.Value == "intracom diensten")
                            {
                                ddl.Enabled = false;
                                ddl.SelectedItem.Text = "0";
                                ddl.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#F2F2F2");
                            }
                            else if (ddlBTWregime.SelectedItem.Value == "BTW 6%")
                            {
                                ddl.Enabled = false;
                                ddl.SelectedItem.Text = "6";
                                ddl.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#F2F2F2");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                ddl.Enabled = true;
                                ddl.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFFFF");
                            }
                        }

                        // Add the control to the TableCell
                        cell.Controls.Add(ddl);
                        // Add the TableCell to the TableRow
                        row.Cells.Add(cell);
                    }
                }
                // And finally, add the TableRow to the Table
                tblArtikels.Rows.Add(row);
            }

            //Sore the current Rows Count in ViewState
            numOfRows = rowsCount;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            huidigDocument.log("DocumentToevoegen.aspx", "Genereer tabel", ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Below the .cs file i'm using to get the list items from SharePoint =>

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

namespace AdminCareWeb
{
public class Klanten
{
    SharePointContextToken contextToken;
    string accessToken;
    string currentUser;
    Uri sharepointUrl;
    string contextTokenString;
    Document logging = new Document();

    #region props

    public string KlantID { get; set; }
    public string KlantNaam { get; set; }
    public string KlantAdres { get; set; }
    public string KlantAdres2 { get; set; }
    public string KlantPostcode { get; set; }
    public string KlantPlaats { get; set; }
    public string KlantLand { get; set; }
    public string KlantOndernemingsnummerVoorloopcode { get; set; }
    public string KlantOndernemingsnummer { get; set; }

    #endregion

    //Lijst maken van alle landen uit de SharePoint lijst landen.
    public Dictionary<string, string> Landen()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> landenLijst = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        try
        {
            contextToken = PassThrough.contextToken;
            sharepointUrl = PassThrough.sharepointUrl;
            accessToken = PassThrough.accessToken;
            ClientContext clientContext = TokenHelper.GetClientContextWithAccessToken(sharepointUrl.ToString(), accessToken);

            // Lijst met Landen ophalen en dropdown vullen
            List oListLanden = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Lijst landen");

            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            CamlQuery cQLand = new CamlQuery();
            cQLand.ViewXml = "<View><Query></Query></View>";
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection landListItem = oListLanden.GetItems(cQLand);
            clientContext.Load(landListItem, items => items.Include(
                item => item["ID"],
                item => item["LDnaam"]));
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem landItem in landListItem)
            {
                string ID = landItem["ID"].ToString();
                string landNaam = landItem["LDnaam"].ToString();
                landenLijst.Add(ID, landNaam);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logging.log("Klanten.cs", "Landen ophalen", ex.Message.ToString());
        }

        return landenLijst;
    }



    //Lijst maken van alle postcodes uit de SharePoint lijst postcodes en gemeentes.
    public Dictionary<string, string> Postcodes()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> postcodesLijst = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        try
        {
            contextToken = PassThrough.contextToken;
            sharepointUrl = PassThrough.sharepointUrl;
            accessToken = PassThrough.accessToken;
            ClientContext clientContext = TokenHelper.GetClientContextWithAccessToken(sharepointUrl.ToString(), accessToken);

            //Lijst met postcodes ophalen en dropdown opvullen
            List oListPostcodes = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Lijst postcodes");

            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            CamlQuery cQPostcodes = new CamlQuery();
            cQPostcodes.ViewXml = "<View>"
                + "<Query>"
                + "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='PCgemeente'/></OrderBy>"
                + "</Query>"
                + "</View>";

            //Lijst aanmaken met het resultaat van de uitgevoerde query.
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection postcodeListItem = oListPostcodes.GetItems(cQPostcodes);
            clientContext.Load(postcodeListItem, items => items.Include(
                item => item["ID"],
                item => item["PCgemeente"]));
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem postcodeItem in postcodeListItem)
            {
                string ID = postcodeItem["ID"].ToString();
                string gemeente = postcodeItem["PCgemeente"].ToString();
                postcodesLijst.Add(ID, gemeente);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logging.log("Klanten.cs", "Postcodes ophalen", ex.Message.ToString());
        }

        return postcodesLijst;
    }

    //Lijst maken van alle landen uit de SharePoint lijst landen.
    public Dictionary<string, string> KlantenOphalen()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> klantenLijst = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        try
        {
            contextToken = PassThrough.contextToken;
            sharepointUrl = PassThrough.sharepointUrl;
            accessToken = PassThrough.accessToken;
            ClientContext clientContext = TokenHelper.GetClientContextWithAccessToken(sharepointUrl.ToString(), accessToken);

            // Lijst met Landen ophalen en dropdown vullen
            List oListKLanten = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Lijst Relaties");

            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            CamlQuery cQKlant = new CamlQuery();
            cQKlant.ViewXml = "<View>"
            + "<Query>"
            + "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='RLtyperelatie' /><Value Type='Choice'>Klant</Value></Eq></Where>"
            + "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='RLnaam'/></OrderBy>"
            + "</Query>"
            + "</View>";

            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection klantListItem = oListKLanten.GetItems(cQKlant);
            clientContext.Load(klantListItem, items => items.Include(
                item => item["RLnaam"]));
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem klantItem in klantListItem)
            {
                string klantNaam = klantItem["RLnaam"].ToString();
                klantenLijst.Add(klantNaam, klantNaam);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logging.log("Klanten.cs", "Klanten ophalen", ex.Message.ToString());
        }

        return klantenLijst;
    }
}
}
```

Anyone have some suggestions to speed up. Well the problem is now it takes 7 -8 seconds before the page is showing up. Postbacks takes 3-5 seconds.

Comment: Try wrapping some timers around any bits of code that seem to be calling out to SharePoint itself. It could be all kinds of things, poorly optimized iterations, connection issues with SharePoint, that kind of stuff.

Comment: Split your code to separate methods and run perfomance tests (Alt+F2 in visual studio), so u can see witch parts are run slower, or just place debug console output after each line. You need to know what exact slow your program.

Comment: it looks like you have alot of calls to sharepoint. these will be the slow bits. Now my german is terrible, but are you populating dropdowns with options which don't change? you can cache these unchanging lists and just use teh cached values to speed things up

Comment: Well most of the dropdown are changing. I was thinking to load this data by jquery? But as my server side code is hosted at Azure i'm receiving a Cors error. And the SharePoint requests are taking a huge time to load.

Comment: how many items are in your list?